# Azure Web App Working_Set and Private_Memory Definition

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

In Azure Web Apps, we can log into the SCM console at https://[sitename].scm.azurewebsites.net. If we navigate to the Process Explorer menu option, we see a listing of all processes running on the Web App.

I cannot find a definition of what exactly working_set and private_memory are. Can anyone tell me in detail what these mean? Thanks!

Comment: It did dawn on me that since Kudu is open source, I can conceivably trace back through the code and find these answers. If nobody answers, I'll do so when I get a chance and post the answer back.

Comment: Did you find anything if you traced it back, or have you come to any conclusions in other ways?

Comment: @jwweiler, this is the best explanation I've seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299010/average-memory-working-set-and-memory-working-set-in-azure. I have not verified the answer yet. I solved the issue at hand that prompted this post, then forgot about it. :-)